# ClickListener event for custom InfoWindow returns the same value for all markers.

Tags: android

the code runs good without errors however the click event for the custom infowindow returns the same value (toast message) for both marker,i need the custom Infowindows to return the specific toast message within when clicked.

code:

public class HotelActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private final static int MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION = 101;

public static final String Hotdetails = "com.myaddress.Hotdetails";

@Override
public Resources getResources(){
    return super.getResources();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){// ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

    LatLng location1 = new LatLng(9.0454, 7.4797);
    LatLng location2 = new LatLng(9.036190, 7.480130);

    //for location1

        Marker ClassMark = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(eclass).title("E-Class Resorts").snippet("3 star resort of excellence").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.eclasses)));

        InfoWindowData Classinfo = new InfoWindowData();
        Classinfo.setImage(("eclass"));
        Classinfo.setRatings("the very best");

        CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap ClassInfoWindow = new CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(this);
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(ClassInfoWindow);
        ClassMark.setTag(Classinfo);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is E-class", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                   
            }
        });

        //for Location2

        Marker StateMark = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Statement).title("Statement HOTEL").snippet("5 star hotel of excellence").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.statementes)));

        InfoWindowData stateinfo = new InfoWindowData();
        stateinfo.setImage(("allstates"));
        stateinfo.setRatings("quite nice");           

        CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap stateInfoWindow = new CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(this);
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(stateInfoWindow);

        StateMark.setTag(stateinfo);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is Statement", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });

         mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(4.0f));
        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(4.0f);
        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(17.0f);
        //mMap.resetMinMaxZoomPreference();

    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
           }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){ //&& ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13.0f));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0f));
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(8.0f);
                    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(17.0f);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This service requires location permissions to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the second `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` you're erasing the previous one, because the GoogleMap object can only have one.

Instead of this, set the listener only once and, in this one, find which marker the user clicked with the Marker param passed in the `onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)`method.

Try something like this:

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        if (marker.equals(StateMark)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is Statement", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (marker.equals(ClassMark)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is E-Class", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: worked for me, thanks a lot for the fast response too.